# Nutch crawling fails after few iterations with Runtime Exception

Tags: web-crawler, nutch, depth

We are using Nutch 2.3.1-src version. Executing crawl command with 200 depth. But after few iterations, fetching fails with the below mentioned runtime exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: KeyValue size too large
Exception at GoraRecordWriter.class while writing to datastore: KeyValue size too large
```

Crawl command:

```
/Data/Apache/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local/bin/crawl /Data/Apache/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local/urls crawl-nutch http://localhost:9200/test/ 200
```

Answer (score 0):

can I ask you which backend you are using? 
If it is HBase, then you have update the max KeyValue size configuration. This configuration is on the hbase-site.xml file which by default is 10MB

`<property>
<name>hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize</name>
<value>10485760</value>
</property>`

Comment: yes, we are using HBase. Thanks, updated this property. Earlier the process got aborted with this error. after updating this property, we are still getting that error. but it is not stopping the process. Any idea to completely get rid of this error?

Comment: is the config file the same for all processes? I mean you updated it, but where exactly? it has to be the same (or all of them should point to the same) hbase cluster, and nutch (gora should be able to pick up the config file that nutch is pointing to)